# Can Firefox's password manager sign in automatically to websites?

Tags: firefox

[Firefox's password manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import) can fill website login forms, but is it possible to sign in automatically?
I prefer clearing cookies on browser shutdown and don't want to install add-ons.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want a gun that does not have the ability to fire.  No cookies = browser unable to see what your login name is; and how would Firefox know to press "Enter" without an add-on?

Comment: @MarkStewart: 
 
I haven't disabled cookies

Answer (score -1):

No, Firefox cannot do what you are asking natively (without add ons)

You are essentially asking for a functionality that would copy the cookies elsewhere (encrypt them as you are worried about storing them in first place) and when firefox starts, decrypt and copy back...

Comment: I don't think I'm asking about cookies. Login credentials are saved, I want that Firefox sends the filled form automatically.

Comment: Right, for the first logon, after that cookies are used to keep you logged in, so there are two approaches, but still not possible with native Firefox

Answer (score -1):

A: This problem is already solved. By exactly providing you with a cookie. Contrary to popular believe cookies aren't actually bad thing and have legitimate use and are save if applied correctly. Or at least saver than any home-cooked solution (Ok, cookies are not perfect, but who knew when they were invented).

B: Automatically signing in with password managers is a terrible idea! This is literally asking to get fished by bogus websites and you will not be any the wiser if it happens.

To only reasonable solution is to use a cookie manager plugin that allows you to save a list of cookies from being purged. Or use Privacy Badger + an Ad-blocker and disable third party cookies, to get rid of the worst kinds of cookies.

If your worried about tracking through cookies: there are way more sophisticated mechanisms than tracking cookies today. Cookies just gives a short cut to identify you. Look into browser fingerprinting techniques and enjoy the nightmares it induces for days ;-)

Comment: "Automatically signing in with password managers is a terrible idea! This is literally asking to get fished by bogus websites and you will not be any the wiser if it happens." - is this an issue when the password manager verifies that page URL matches?

Comment: That depends on two things: 1. the security of your network. If you have an attacker on your network preforming ARP/DNS spoofing. he can impersonate what ever domain he wants. This is very easy to do. 2. on how diligently the URL matching is done by the pw-manager AND the browser. Just some month ago there was a vuln fixed in lastpass where one could craft specially encoded URLs which where decoded to look like a URL you have saved.